# I used tabview inside the bottom navigation, but recyclerview is not showing

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, layout-inflater, tabview

I inflated view and created xml layout  for tab. iam getting views Textview Edittext everything but Recyclerview is not showing in tabview

Comment: You should add some code to get more relevant answers.Please show what have you tried

Comment: post some code here where you get the error

Comment: iam not getting any error

Comment: just layout is showing empty

Comment: Then show your code that you have tried yet

Comment: I uploaded my code please check